# SPDT switching of high voltage connections

Tags: high-voltage

I have a high voltage system (<=20 kV) with two different polarity supplies, the output of one of these will go to the system under test at any given time. I need to be able to electronically switch between these inputs. The switching will only occur when the voltages are off. The current while running is <1 mA. The switch should be latching, ideally.

The only solutions to this I have found are large bulky vacuum relays. These appear to be designed to switch high currents at voltage.

Is there a simple way to float some kind of SPDT switch, contactor, or relay to achieve the above compactly?

Comment: Something like this https://dc-components.com/wp-content/uploads/GIGAVAC-G18-HV-Relay.pdf or this https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=5-1773450-5_sec7_K61&DocType=CS&DocLang=English&DocFilename=ENG_CS_5-1773450-5_sec7_K61_0313_5-1773450-5_Sec7_K61.pdf

Comment: High-voltage contactors are bulky and expensive by necessity. HV requires more insulation and size to prevent arcing.

Comment: You're going to need a kilovac, I don't think there's any way around it.

Comment: @Antonio51 The first link there isn't rated for 20 kV. The second one would work, though.

Comment: Yes I've used the Gigavacs before. They work well. Question was aimed at something smaller/cleaner/cheaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, those big bulky relays are big and bulky for a reason. 20 kV is a lot, and requires care and large clearances.

Up to a handful of kilovolts there are some options with standard unsealed air relays (which would need to have some arc extinguishing methods, making them even larger), but at 20 kV you're pretty much limited to kilovacs--maybe not even the vacuum ones, but SF₆-filled ones. (Power transmission switchgear might be another option, but that's much bigger, much bulkier, and requires a large exclusion zone that people aren't allowed to enter. Not a good option.)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the switching is only with the power off, you don't have make/break issues.  This really helps, as it is arcing that causes the main problems.

If this is just for test purposes, and you don't want the expense of dedicated high voltage relays, I'd consider using solenoids, linear motors, or servos with cranks, to automate the operation of off-the-shelf electric fence knife switches.

[image]

(Image from one of many similar items on eBay [enter link description here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/153398699131?mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=710-53481-19255-0&campid=5338757644&toolid=20006&customid=6e29ed439ec51f05b032f23281ea97e8).)

They have clearance for 15KV+ under wet conditions, and in my experience are easily good for 20KV+ in the dry.

If you can be patient full spec kilovacs k61/k62 come up on eBay from time to time, some as low as $200 [used k61](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/275596916620?hash=item402adb378c:g:msAAAOSwAkxjrF9e&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA4JOsdDhHcMCA8mebTjxCncgjgj9oXThFBish2N%2BomRZ5Jub%2BsGZ0%2FMN04LdFifQstnrKd6ofpgTjL1j3kfXFSBzaOVx47auNRzoN%2FEcH8cSb2hmIBo66zm1ruRQFA1mojqSgTE7PrFzNY%2FTCb4qWcJDJ%2Fa9UCYPqF6zrcbSg4CLHNLb6%2FdbL%2FgjR5G8xEi1uXBkfcoWByjbeECmSLOV8aTe72qdxt%2BeUF8CY1WtIb%2F9D%2BXES3e4erk%2F3TQUE4PRDEKwhhfcDNhDcdAAbPXCY%2Fc5RBCSdQu%2F%2FSoR2lsSfJjDN%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR5zXjcvqYg) instead of the normal price of $2000+